# Where to find spectra from Las Campanas Redshift Survey?

Tags: galaxy, spectra

I am interested in the optical spectrum of a galaxy. In SIMBAD the reference for the redshift of my galaxy is the Las Campanas Redshift Survey. Hence I am looking for the optical spectrum from which the redshift was estimated.

Answer (score 1):

LCRS catalog data should be accessible at [VizieR:VII/203](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=VII/203/catalog).
The associated paper is [Schectman et al. 1996](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996ApJ...470..172S/abstract).